# Why Entity Framework's Find is not strongly typed? (gets an object[])

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework

Couldn't find any proper answer.

Why the `Find` property of Entity Framework gets an array of `object`s for primary key?

The IDE has generated so many classes and properties, is that a problem to generate the exact `Find` method, according to your model?

For example if your Primary Keys are GroupName and ID, I'd expect the `Find` method to be:

```
  Find(string groupName, int id)
```

Further more, if I am not very much mistaken, I remember it was just like even before Entity Framework... Just by using Visual Studio Generating tools and ado.net.

Comment: [`Find` method is defined on `IDbSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679596%28v=vs.113%29.aspx), how would you know how any given `T` defines its primary keys? And you can't have heterogenously typed `params`.

Comment: So wouldn't it be better if the IDE generated a class for each table?